# ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool

Tags: asp.net, iis, connection-string

I have a website folder on my local machine. I have already used aspnet_regsql.exe on the SQL Server hosted on windows server. I have to deploy this website to a different server (on IIS).

When i user visual studio on my local machine to create roles, so that I can deploy it afterwards. But I am getting the below error,

```
Line 44:     public static bool ValidLogin(string username, string password)
Line 45:     {
Line 46:         return Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
Line 47:     }
Line 48:
```

My connection string is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>

      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="UBCATDB" connectionString="Data Source=\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=UB_CAT;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="UBCATEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.UBCATDB.csdl|res://*/App_Code.UBCATDB.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.UBCATDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=UB_CAT;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot; " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>

      <system.web>
         <identity impersonate="true" />
        <authorization>
          <allow roles="Administrator" />
          <allow users="ubcat" />
        </authorization>
        <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>

        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms name="UBCATSqlAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"
            timeout="60" />
        </authentication>
        <sessionState timeout="60" />
        <membership defaultProvider="UBCATSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="UBCATSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="UBCATDB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="UBCAT" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
          </providers>
        </membership>

        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UBCATSqlRoleProvider" cookieTimeout="60">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add connectionStringName="UBCATDB" applicationName="UBCAT" name="UBCATSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
          </assemblies>
          <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
          </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<add name="UBCATDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=UB_CAT;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`, i.e. a dot in front of `\sqlexpress`? P.S. you didn't give the error message.

Comment: You haven't actually posted any error message.

Comment: Error message is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.

Comment: It looks like you should remove the `Persist Security Info=True` (ref: [social.msdn.microsoft.com/.../persist-security-info](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb97cafd-d3aa-450a-ad33-f8e450c8a7b3/persist-security-info?forum=sqldataaccess) and use `Integrated Security=true` in the connection string (ref: [www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Comment: @Andrew Mortan I used Integrated Security = true, but I am getting the below error,

Comment: Invalid object name 'dbo.Logins'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Logins'.

Source Error: 


Line 36: 
Line 37:         context.Logins.AddObject(login);
Line 38:         context.SaveChanges();
Line 39:     }
Line 40:

Comment: I have added Logins table into the database, how to include this table in the database model (.edmx file)